# lightning:path component trying to show record detail?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am working in the Community, and I have created a custom component using the [`lightning:path` item](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:path/documentation) in order to hide the "Mark Stage as Complete" button. However, when I put it on a Community Page, it attempts to show the record under the Key Fields:

[image: Community Error Under Key Fields]

Component:

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId" >
<aura:attribute name="variant" type="String" default="linear"/>
<aura:attribute name="hideUpdateButton" type="Boolean" default="true"/>

<lightning:path aura:id="path" 
    recordId="{!v.recordId}"
    variant="linear"
    hideUpdateButton="true"
    onselect="{!c.handleSelect}"
></lightning:path>

</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
({
    handleSelect : function (component, event, helper) {
     var stepName = event.getParam("detail").value;
    }
})
```

The standard path object shows up just fine, but is there a way to hide the record view?